# Remove layers from WP8 Map control via button click

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to remove layers/pushpins from a Map control at the push of a button? Below is my code to add a layer:

```
        MapLayer layer1 = new MapLayer();

        Pushpin pushpin1 = new Pushpin();
        pushpin1.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(51.503147, -0.113245);
        pushpin1.Content = "Pin 1";

        MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay();
        overlay1.Content = pushpin1;
        overlay1.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(51.503147, -0.113245);
        layer1.Add(overlay1);

        WC_WATMap.Layers.Add(layer1);
```

Comment: WC_WATMap.Layers.Clear(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to remove them completely and just want them not shown any more, just set the Visibility to Collapsed.

```
pushpin1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

OR

```
Pushpin pushpin = (Pushpin)this.FindName("pushpin1");
pushpin.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

might be somewhere to start if you need to clear them completely

```
Map.Layers.Remove()
Map.Layers.Remove((MapOverlay)this.FindName("layer1"));
```

FINAL CREDIT TO Anthony Russell for the answer in comment form

```
WC_WATMap.Layers.Clear();
```

Comment: Although Anthony Russell's answer was the actual solution